# Couldn't Create a Foreign Key in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables, let's call em `table1` and `table2`.

- The Primary Key of `table1` is CHAR(36), Not Null, and Unique.
- The column in `table2` I'm trying to make an FK is, also, CHAR(36), Not Null, and Unique.
- Both tables have zero records.
- `table1` has four Foreign Keys, all pointing at other tables.  (None of them point at `table2`.)

When I try to define the PK of `table1` as an FK in `table2` Workbench wouldn't let me select the field.  The check box for the column in `table2` simply would not be selected, no matter what I did.

Comment: you're linking char fields - make sure the same collation/charset is used for both.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create this Foreign Key, I had to run it as a query directly, bypassing Workbench's GUI.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_schema`.`table_two` 
ADD INDEX `fk_to_table_one_pk_idx` (`table_two_column` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `my_schema`.`table_two` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_to_table_one_pk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`table_two_column`)
    REFERENCES `my_schema`.`table_one` (`table_one_column`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I ran this query and, ta-friggin-da, the FK was in place and no error was thrown.  I've heard that Workbench is pretty flaky and I think this confirms that.

After I had the FK in place I marked the column in `table2` as the PK via the GUI without issue.  The SQL might have worked just fine with the `table2` column marked as the PK but I did not run it that way, so I cannot confirm that.

Comment: Try thinking about the design process more in terms of EER, rather than ordinary (My)SQL code. MySQL Workbench tries to enforce proper conditions to allow certain operations. If it didn't allow to set a foreign key then there was a reason (e.g. the missing PK).

Answer (score 0):

Try DISABLE KEYS or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

make sure to

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after.